# How do you filter records from a union query using values from a combo box list?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a datasheet form `frmDatasheet` linked to a Query named `qryAll`. The datasheet form is a subform of `frmMain` form. In frmMain, I have a combo box named `filterCombo`.
The `filterCombo` is suposed to make `frmDatasheet` display all records whos `entryDate` field is January, February and March only.
I have used this method before with a table and it worked fine but doesn't seems to work on a union query.

My code is as follows:

```
Private Sub filterCombo_AfterUpdate()
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM qryAll WHERE MONTH(entryDate) = 1 OR MONTH(entryDate) = 2 OR MONTH(entryDate) = 3"
'Task2 = "SELECT * FROM qryAll WHERE MONTH(entryDate) = 1 OR 2 OR 3"

If Me.filterCombo.Value = "First quarter(Q1)" Then
Me.frmDatasheet.Form.RecordSource = strSQL
Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Since data cannot be edited through a UNION query, why bind a form to it? Your SQL is missing `OR` operator and has extra parenthesis at end. Try: `WHERE Month(entryDate) <= 3`.

Comment: @June7 I am only displaying the data for a quick inspection and not editing. Also even though I make the form unbound and display data through sql statement, it still would not filter. I will correct the post for missing OR and the parenthesis. Thanks

Comment: @June7 with `WHERE Month(entryDate) <= 3` still doesn't work

Comment: Tested with my UNION query and filter works. What do you mean by "doesn't work" - error message, wrong result, nothing happens?

Comment: I get no record and there is no error either.

Comment: Edited mistake: @June7 I inspected again and again, could you have a look at my query? `qryAll = SELECT 'N/A' AS ItemName, tbl1.PONo, tbl1.Description, tbl1.Category, tbl1.SupplierName, tbl1.NetPrice, tbl1.entryDate, FROM tbl1 UNION ALL SELECT tbl2.ItemName, 'N/A' AS PONo, tbl2.Description,'claim' AS Category, 'N/A' AS SupplierName, tbl2.NetPrice, tbl2.entryDate, tbl2.Comments, FROM tbl2"`

Comment: @June7 Thanks I figured of the problem. Had to inspect the combobox elements as well. there should be a space between r and the parenthesis in `First quarter(Q1)` Please add your code as answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your SQL syntax so explore other issues, such as misspelling.

Consider a simpler expression:

`WHERE Month(entryDate) <= 3`